# Trace of a matrix $A$

Tags: trace

Suppose we are given a matrix

$$A = \begin{pmatrix}
x & y \\
-y & x
\end{pmatrix}
$$

where $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x^2+y^2=1$.

Then is, $\textrm{tr}(A)$ not equal to $0$?

If yes, then how is this possible?

Comment: If $A = \left(\matrix{x&y\\-y&x}\right)$ then the trace of $A$ is $2x$, the sum of the elements along the diagonal.

Comment: $\operatorname{Tr}'A)=2x$, by definition. You may note $A$ is a rotation matrix around the origin in the plane.

Answer (score 1):

If
$$
A =\pmatrix{x & y \\ -y & x}
$$
with $x^2 + y^2 = 1$, then the trace of $A$ is
$$
\text{trace}(A) = x + x = 2x.
$$
This is zero exactly when $x=0$ and this would mean $y = \pm 1$.

Answer (score 1):

The trace of a matrix is the sum of the entries along its main diagonal (the one from the top-left to bottom-right of the matrix) For the matrix you wrote down

$$
\text{trace}\begin{pmatrix}x & y \\ -y & x\end{pmatrix} = x + x = 2x,
$$

which is $0$ only if $x = 0$.

However, it is true that

$$
\text{trace}\begin{pmatrix}x & y \\ y & -x\end{pmatrix} = x - x = 0
$$

for every choice of $x$ and $y$ you described. In general, the trace of a nonzero matrix need not be nonzero.